# Aligning button below text view no matter length of text with swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, text, view

I have a text view that displays data from a database. Typically the text is no more than a few sentences but there is a possibility a user will add multiple paragraphs.

I'm trying to align a button below this text view no matter how much text is displayed.

Is there a way to do this with swift? I tried re adjusting elements in the storyboard with no luck.

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: show your tried code, and show your UI

Comment: Updated with my ui, no real code to display now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not set contraints for the items in your storyboard. This is a classic Auto Layout issue.

A simple solution for this could be to embed it all in a stack.

First select all the items in your storyboard, form the **document outline** pane:
 1. UIImageView
 2. Title
 3. UIScrollView
 4. 'Share Updates' and 'Discussion' button.

Now, click on the **Embed In Stack button**
[image]

Now try running the simulator and check the outcome.

On the other hand, you can also specify individual constraints. For this purpose, I believe that embedding in stack is all that is necessary.

And here is the official link for Auto Layouts, which is a **must know** for developing:
[Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1)

**Tips**:
1. Use 'spacing' attribute of the stack 
2. Try learning and embedding stacks into stacks, if in case you want custom spacing of the two buttons. (For example, the two buttons could be inside a stack with a larger spacing, and that stack will be co-existing with other elements of the parent stack, with lesser spacing.)

Answer (score 0):

Set button's Top Space constraint to your text view and add this in the scrollview.It will automatically scroll if your text is lengthy and the button will be shown at bottom of textview.

Answer (score 0):

give your button vertical spacing to textView (make sure you have scroll View so then if textView size is long then you can scroll down to see that button)

Comment: click on your button press ctrl and drag it to your textview and then click on vertical spacing and your work will be done 100%